# Angular 9 filter results of async pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-pipe

I am kind of new at angular and I am doing an application to learn better. I have a problem about binding and filtering  results of a http call. At below code I try to bind a list of some data.

At service I have a call like this

```
 getTestFields(): Observable<Engagement[]> {
   return this.httpClient.get<Engagement[]>(this.url + '/testFields');
 }
```

It basically returns a list of some test fields; and at component.ts I am binding the results of call to an observable variable.

```
dataSet$: Observable<Engagement[]>;
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataSet$ = this.service.getTestFields();
}
```

And at the html template I bind the data like below:

```
<table class="table table-hover" *ngIf="dataSet$ | async as resultSet; else loading">
        <tr *ngFor="let item of resultSet" >
            <td>{{item.testName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.planned}}</td>
            <td>{{item.workingOn}}</td>
            <td>{{item.reviewed}}</td>
        </tr>   </table>
```

Until here I have no problem; I get the data successfully and show in table. The problem is filtering; I couldn't figure out how I can filter the data that I already got from server. I don't want to make server calls for filtering data, I want to filter the current list that I already got.

I tried something like below but it didn't work.

```
filter() {
    this.dataSet$ = this.dataSet$.pipe(
    switchMap(data => {
      return data.filter(p => p.planned)
    })
  );
 }
```

How can I filter existing observable list without sending a new call to server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the rxjs `map` operator coupled with array `filter`.

Map transforms the observable, so in this case we are using it to transform the array to only include the items where `planned` is true.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
.....
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataSet$ = this.service.getTestFields().pipe(
    map(data => data.filter(p => p.planned)),
  );
}
```

You can also `filter` emissions from the Observable using the `filter` operator of `rxjs` but I don't think you need it in this case.

================ Use of RxJS Filter ===================

```
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataSet$ = this.service.getTestFields().pipe(
    // make sure data is truthy and has a length before emitting to 
    // the consumer (in this case it is the HTML).
    filter(data => !!data && !!data.length),
  );
}
```

Comment: in which cases better to use like this than rxjs filter ? Is there a particular difference?

Comment: Yes, `filter` of array filters an array on a conditions. The rxjs `filter` operator stops the emission of an observable based on a condition and looking at your example, I don't think you want this. I have edited my answer to include an example of `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with AliF50, just little tweak as I am assuming you have a filter button or somehow you want to filter out once data is loaded.

```
dataSet$: Observable<Engagement[]>;
ngOnInit(): void {
 filter();
}

filter() {
    this.dataSet$ = this.service.getTestFields().pipe(
    map(data => data.filter(p => p.planned)),
  );
  );
 }
```

There is one more scenario that you never want to go to the server once you load the data then you probably need to subscribe at the component level.

like

```
dataSet: Engagement[];
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataSet = this.service.getTestFields().subscribe(response => this.dataSet = 
   response);
}

filter() {
    this.dataSet = this.dataSet.filter(data => data.planned === true)
  }
```

Comment: What you mean with never go to server? subscribe makes kind of cache ?

Comment: No, it will make one request for the first time, and since you are going to hold all the values in this.dataSet which is not observable and now if you try to filter anything so it will on that object so no api call will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I came across with a mixed solution; separating responsibilities was the key to get my problem solved; I had an autocomplete implemented within a `async` pipe to it's own list however I was not able to handle filters in a proper, so here we go:

**my-dear-autocomplete.component.ts**

```
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  Output, EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyInterface } from '~interfaces-whatsoever';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({...})
export class MyDearAutocompleteComponent
  implements OnInit
{
  @Input() controlName: string;
  @Input() control: FormControl;
  @Input() options: MyInterface[];
  @Output() selectOptionEvent = new EventEmitter<MyInterface>();
  filteredOptions: Observable<MyInterface[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.control.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''), map(name => this.isOptionNameMatch(name)));
  }

  isOptionNameMatch(value: string): MyInterface[] {
    const clause = (option: MyInterface) => { do your stuff test here };
    return (typeof value === 'string') ? this.options.filter(clause) : this.options;
  }

  selectOption(value: MyInterface) {
    this.selectOptionEvent.emit(value);
  }
}
```

Where `@Input() options: MyInterface[];` is your full list given by component parents using something like:

```
options$ | async as options; else loading
...
<app-my-dear-autocomplete ... [options]="options" ... ></app-my-dear-autocomplete>
```

**my-dear-autocomplete.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" fxFlex="100">
  <mat-label>My dear option list</mat-label>
  <input type="text" required matInput [matAutocomplete]="optionAutocomplete" [formControl]="control"/>
  <mat-autocomplete #optionAutocomplete="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selectOption($event.option.value)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{ option.whatsoever }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Doing it and using the autocomplete like a component subscribing to it output helped me handling the selection events along with other components.

Hope it helps and I am open to suggestions of course